# Use varchar and uniqueidentifier to search in XML column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT [Event_Id] 
FROM [Processing].[Event]
WHERE [RefEventTypeId] = 8
  AND [Description] LIKE '%' + (SELECT [Guid] 
                                FROM [Security].[WebUser] 
                                WHERE Login = 'test') +'%'
```

When I tried use one of my select parameters with `LIKE` I get this error:

> The data types varchar and uniqueidentifier are incompatible in the
>   add operator.

I have changed this select to some string just to check is that a problem with select and got another error:

```
SELECT [Event_Id] 
FROM [Processing].[Event]
WHERE [RefEventTypeId] = 8
  AND [Description] LIKE '%' + 'E522A826-C538' +'%'
```

Error:

> Argument data type xml is invalid for argument 1 of like function.

My `Description` column is of type `XML`. Can I get some search using `LIKE`? And how to use `SELECT` in that case if Guid that I have been searching for is uniqueidentifier?

P.S. Sorry for grammar.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Like only works on string like data types.  Although XML and GUIDs look like strings they are not.  You could try casting these fields so the data types match (i.e. CAST(xml as VARCHAR(255)) LIKE CAST(GUID AS VARCHAR(255)).  Watch out for truncation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, keep in mind using %something% for a LIKE clause, could be very loooong.
Your query should be something like this:

```
SELECT [Event_Id] 
FROM [Processing].[Event]
WHERE [RefEventTypeId] = 8
  AND CONVERT(nvarchar(max), [Description]) LIKE '%' + (SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(32), [Guid])
                                FROM [Security].[WebUser] 
                                WHERE Login = 'test') +'%'
```

Comment: This option is working. Thanks.
And in case of LIKE. What would be work faster?

Comment: Unfortunately if you need that you just have to wait. Another option would be to reshape your tables to keep those info not sunk in a nvarchar/xml field but to dedicate them an internal column or link to a correlation table

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not a designer of tables. I just need to work with that.. 
Ok, thank you for great answer.